# Problem with log out function in a github tutorial

Tags: reactjs, auth0

i wanna be able to log out of my app, i'm following a github tutorial everything good until i found it was incomplete there was a log out function it says that i just have to do a callback
[image: that logout button is what i want to work but it doesn't]

the log out funtion is https://github.com/Cazadorx/chatkit-sample-client/blob/master/src/auth/auth.js

and my button is https://github.com/Cazadorx/chatkit-sample-client/blob/master/src/components/UserHeader/index.js

i'm learning programming so forgive me if im doing something wrong

i'm using react to code , auth0 for authentification and netlify for deploy pls help me

Comment: Please include related code into the question itself. [mcve] External repo may and likely will change making this question useless for future readers.

Comment: ok ok i'll rewrite it , i did try to follow the tips i think i was a good question

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

You should not be storing sensitive info (tokens) in localStorage. Instead, you should have the token persist in memory (a variable in this case), and when the app refreshes let the cookie session log the user in using silent authentication.

This probably sounds like a lot of work, but it is being handled by auth0 in your app and isn't hard to implement.

As far as your logout issue, you should clear out any tokens, then call the logout method of the auth0 `webAuth` object (this calls the auth0 logout endpoint to clear out the session/cookie for the user).
https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9#logout

In addition, auth0 has a quickstart you can look at. It uses a newer library, auth0-spa-js, but it is similar in nature to auth0.js. I would recommend moving to that library if you have no reason to stay with auth0.js.

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login

Comment: i'll check it out and make you know